# how to centralize the way you set icons with enum and singleton in an app

Tags: ios, enums, icons, singleton, project

Okey!

So how can I centralizing the way I set my icons in a larger scale project.

Insted of setting icons with `[UIImage ImageNamed: @"iconNamed"];` everywhere and having to look into all the places in your project to change the string whenever an icon is being changed
and insted of having a long list of method implementations returning a string.

The end result should be like:

[image: iOS autocomplete list with iconTypes]

Comment: This isn't a question.

Comment: okey so let me refrase myself before you downwote plis.
I had the option to "Answer your own question - share your knowledge"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively just have constants defined like Apple does for global keys...

In the `.h` file:

```
extern NSString *const kIconMenuSmallWht;
extern NSString *const kIconMenuBigWht;
extern NSString *const kIconShoppingSmall;
extern NSString *const kIconShoppingBig;
extern NSString *const kIconSleepingSmall;
extern NSString *const kIconSleepingBig;
```

In the `.m` file:

```
NSString *const kIconMenuSmallWht  = @"ag_icons_btn_menu_wht";
NSString *const kIconMenuBigWht    = @"c";
NSString *const kIconShoppingSmall = @"ag_icons_idx_ico_shopping_wht";
NSString *const kIconShoppingBig   = @"ag_icons_idx_ico_shopping_wht";
NSString *const kIconSleepingSmall = @"ag_icons_idx_ico_shopping_wht_120";
NSString *const kIconSleepingBig   = @"ag_icons_idx_ico_hotel_wht_120";
```

These are constants... **global variables are not always bad!**

(and many feel singletons are just globals anyway and are just as evil)

This will also give autocomplete in **Xcode** and have a single place to go for updates/changes but is simpler and has no method calls or objects to create so better performance (albeit likely infinitesimally better performance).

Comment: well, some things are men to only exist in one 'version' if you ask me - such as icon names :)
I never found this way of doing it before I put my own little solution together. Gonna try this one as well

Answer (score 1):

So first you create a .h file like `@interface MyIcons : NSObject`

and you kick off your singleton implementation with:

`+(MyIcons *)sharedIcons ;`

followed by:

```
    typedef enum {
       IconMenuSmallWht,
       IconMenuBigWht,
       IconShoppingSmall,
       IconShoppingBig,
       IconSleepingSmall,
       IconSleepingBig,
    } iconType;

    - (NSString*) iconToString:(iconType) chooseIcon;
```

in the .m file you finish up your singleton implementation first:

```
    +(MyIcons *)sharedIcons {
static dispatch_once_t once;
static MyIcons *sharedIcons = nil;

dispatch_once(&once, ^{
    sharedIcons = [[self alloc] init];
});
return sharedIcons;
}
```

and you end with doing:

```
   - (NSString*) iconToString:(iconType) chooseIcon {
NSString *result = nil;

switch(chooseIcon) {
    case IconMenuSmallWht:
        result = @"ag_icons_btn_menu_wht";
        break;
    case IconMenuBigWht:
        result = @"c";
        break;
    case IconShoppingSmall:
        result = @"ag_icons_idx_ico_shopping_wht";
        break;
    case IconShoppingBig:
        result = @"ag_icons_idx_ico_shopping_wht_120";
        break;
    case IconSleepingSmall:
        result = @"ag_icons_idx_ico_hotel_wht";
        break;
    case IconSleepingBig:
        result = @"ag_icons_idx_ico_hotel_wht_120";
        break;
  return result;
}
```

Thats it. It just add icons to the enum and to this switch/case.
and wherevever you want to implement your icons you just #import MyIcons.h

add `[MyIcons SharedIcons]iconToString:` and voila you get your list of choosing.

Hope you enjoy this way of doing it. I know I will! (-:-)